# Partitioning a Rectangle into Congruent Isosceles Triangles

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Is it possible to partition any rectangle into congruent isosceles triangles?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. Note that the acute angle of your triangle must divide $\pi/2$ (look at a corner), so there are countably many such triangles (up to similarity), and hence you get only a countable set of possible ratios of sides.

Comment: Brilliant! $\mbox{}$

Comment: You seem to be saying that there is a one-to-one correspondence between classes of similar triangles and classes of rectangles of sides of a given ratio.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your argument, but if I'm not, I don't see why that has to be true.  Can you elaborate a bit?

Many thanks!

Comment: Not one-to-one, but if we fix triangle (with sides a and b), then both sides of rectangle are linear combinations of a,b with integer coefficients. So, there are at most countably many of them for fixed a,b. 

Comment: Got it.  Thank you!  That is a really nice proof.

Answer (score 9):

If the length divided by the width is rational, then yes.  Just partition the rectangle into congruent squares and cut each square along a diagonal.

Comment: Is this a necessary condition as well?

Comment: Not if you allow infinitely many partitions.  For example, consider the infinite partition of a Golden Rectangle into infinitely many squares.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.11.05

Comment: The argument for necessity would run something like this: 1. By looking at a corner, convince yourself that the triangles must be right (i.e. a half-square). (Some angle on the triangle must divide $90^\circ$; then analyze by cases which angle it can be.) 2. Using irrationally of $\sqrt2$, argue that for any rectangle tiled with half-squares, all short (say) sides must be parallel/perpendicular to each other (as opposed to at $45^\circ$). 3. Whether all short sides are parallel to the sides of the rectangle or perpendicular, you still win.

Comment: @Gerhard: OP requires that _all_ triangles in the partition be congruent.  So your square partition of the golden rectangle leads to a "triangle partition" with infinitely small triangles.  Surely I can do _any_ rectangle if I'm allowed infinitely small triangles, by approximating the ratio of sides by rationals.

Comment: Yeah.  Thank you to those who have posted so far:  I did know, though, that the answer is 'yes' in the cases listed above.  In fact, relaxing any of the hypotheses seems to give a positive answer.  That is, if the triangles need not be isosceles, if they need not be congruent etc.  I was asked this question without the congruency condition by a sophomore student I have.  It seems like, potentially, a good research project, but I  didn't know whether it was 1. known  2. trivial or 3. too hard.  This is outside my area of specialization, so I thought I'd post here to get some sense of things.

Comment: If you knew all that, you could have saved people some work by mentioning it in your original statement. 

Comment: Sorry.  I asked the question I wanted answered, not other related questions.  Requiring that in general here, might make some questions very very very.... very long. :)

Comment: @Gerry: *some* was equal to about epsilon here, so no worries as far as I am concerned.  
@unknown: There is nothing wrong with extremely long questions on MO.  One reason why I like MO is that I can learn a lot from just reading questions, and in this sense longer questions are better than short ones.  Concerning your points {1,2,3}: I am not sure whether the answer is known, but combining Theo's comment with my answer gives a complete characterization.  If one can thrash out the details of Theo's comment, I think it would be neither trivial (2) or too hard (3).  Probably 2.4. 